# UIButton.addTarget not working correctly. Seems to be a timing thing?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating a ViewController with 2 child views.  One is for navigation buttons that is on the top of my main view, and a browser window below (WKWebView)

In the main view controller's viewDidLoad function I create and add these views as subviews.  I then create and add buttons to the navigationView.  I programatically set the constraints of all the buttons to position them and size them manually.

-- Edit --

I noticed that when inspecting the button in the hierarchy, the target is set but the action is null.

[Here is an image showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDx3O.png)

However, when I check the actions on a breakpoint immediately after adding the target, it does appear to be there.

[This was done on a breakpoint immediately after adding the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMBOx.png)

---

I am adding the target as follows

```
btnClose!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCloseClicked), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

The click event does not fire. However if I put a breakpoint after that line, and in the console I look at the actions for the button via

```
po btnClose!.allTargets
```

Then it shows me the target, and then when continuing execution the button works fine.  I assume there's some sort of timing issue as a result but I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm using Swift 4.1.

-- Edit --

Here is all the code involved in that button:  (I removed all the webview code that isn't relevant)

```
public func initialize(){ // called by viewDidLoad
    navigationView = UIView(frame:navigationRect)
    navigationView!.isOpaque = true
    navigationView!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    navigationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 58.0/255.0, green: 60.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(navigationView!)
    addNavigationButtons()
}
private func addNavigationButtons(){
    btnClose = UIButton()
    btnClose!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCloseClicked), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    btnClose!.frame = btnRect // x:0, y:0, width:50, height:50

    btnClose?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btnClose!.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationClose", in: Bundle(identifier:"myframework"), compatibleWith:nil), for:UIControlState.normal)

    navigationView!.addSubview(btnClose!)

    addButtonConstraints()
}

private func addButtonConstraints(){
    // close
    navigationView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:navigationView!, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btnClose!, attribute: .right, multiplier:1.0, constant:0))
    navigationView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:navigationView!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btnClose!, attribute: .centerY, multiplier:1.0, constant:0))
    btnClose!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:btnClose!, attribute: .width, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:MRAIDBrowserWindow.btnWidth)) //btnWidth = 50
    btnClose!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:btnClose!, attribute: .height, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:MRAIDBrowserWindow.btnHeight)) //btnHeight = 50
}

@objc public func onCloseClicked(){ // tried this without @objc
    print("this doesn't work, unless I have a breakpoint stoppage")
}
```

Comment: Put your viewDidLoad code and button creation and button action method.

Comment: okay i did that, thanks

Comment: create the button like this ;-> var button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0)

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onCloseClicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: Thanks vivekDas, but that doesn't work in this version of swift.

Comment: which version you have ?

Comment: It is version 4.1

Comment: let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onCloseClicked), for: .touchUpInside) use like this

Comment: This unfortunately has the same result.

Comment: try to change the selector name

Comment: That also did not work :(

Answer (score 2):

Within method `addNavigationButtons`, put the following the line

```
btnClose!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCloseClicked), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

after

```
navigationView!.addSubview(btnClose!)
```

I think there is a restriction with the new version of swift, if a button is not in a ui view hierarchy, and you try to add a targe-action onto it, it won't actually work. So make sure that the button is added into a ui view hierarchy first.

Comment: I've tried to `addTarget` in lazy var where I create the button and got a warning about using `self`. The button actions didn't work on device but worked on simulator. After moving code after `addSubiew` in code setting up the view it started to work. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should have tell you that I am not so good at setting constraints programatically, so I cannot suggest you a reasonable suggestion to that.

Here is what I have done and I am sharing the working code of your own, with a few only changes...

1. I have added my own Image name, and backgroundColor to button to see some components might effecting the button
2. I have removed the frame which was setting up on btnClose!, because I have noticed that you do not need to tell a frame when you are telling the container for its all sides constraints.

further more you should have a look on to it, down here is he code I have compiled to check -> your actions method calls fine

import UIKit

class MyTestActionViewController: UIViewController {

```
var navigationView : UIView?
var btnClose : UIButton?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.initialize()
}

public func initialize(){ // called by viewDidLoad
    navigationView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x:5, y:55, width:200, height:200))
    navigationView!.isOpaque = true
    navigationView!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    navigationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 58.0/255.0, green: 60.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(navigationView!)
    addNavigationButtons()
}
private func addNavigationButtons(){
    btnClose = UIButton()
    btnClose!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCloseClicked), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    
    btnClose?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    btnClose?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btnClose?.setImage(UIImage(named: "myButtonImage"), for:UIControlState.normal)
    navigationView?.addSubview(btnClose!)
    
    addButtonConstraints()
}

private func addButtonConstraints(){
    // close
    navigationView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:navigationView!, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btnClose!, attribute: .right, multiplier:1.0, constant:0))
    navigationView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:navigationView!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btnClose!, attribute: .centerY, multiplier:1.0, constant:0))
    btnClose!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:btnClose!, attribute: .width, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:50)) //btnWidth = 50
    btnClose!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:btnClose!, attribute: .height, relatedBy:.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant:50)) //btnHeight = 50
}

@objc public func onCloseClicked(){ // tried this without @objc
    print("this doesn't work, unless I have a breakpoint stoppage")
}
```

}

An image showing -> your button action acting properly

[image]

Comment: Thanks for testing this for me.  However, this just confirms that the code is not the problem.  There must be some sort of conflict happening between view controllers in the hierarchy?  The view controller that has this problem is on top of all others, but there is a viewcontroller underneath.  Could that cause a problem?  I have tried disabling user interaction in the lower view controller but it did not help.

Comment: I cannot be sure of it, until I knew all the details.
By the way hierarchy should not disturb the standalone controller functionality, until it is not the subpart of another viewController added using (addChildViewController:), can you share your project so that one can see the all aspects that can effect the functionality??
either share your public project git repository link or some other working option you can choose??